# What is the maximum value of the Combobox.NewIndex property?

Tags: vb6, combobox, recordset

In VB6.0, what is the max value of MyCombobox.NewIndex ? What DataType is it? Why I can NOT set its newIndex to 11001000000 ?   What can I do If I cann't?

Thank you

```
Dim ComboItem As String
With rsTest
        .Sort = "ID Asc"
        .MoveFirst
        While Not .EOF
            ComboItem = .Fields("Code") & " - " & .Fields("Name")
            myCombobox.AddItem (ComboItem)
            myCombobox.ItemData(myCombobox.NewIndex) = .Fields("ID")
            .MoveNext
        Wend
End With
```

Comment: I've posted an answer to your question but does this code actually have a problem?

Comment: You can't explicitly set the `NewIndex` value to a different value. Why would you want to? What effect do you think it would have?

Answer (score 7):

As per [the help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa278147%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), `.NewIndex` is a readonly property that returns the index of the last item added and setting it makes no sense.

As it's an integer, its maximum (usable) value is 32767. When you add the 32769th item to the combobox, the index wraps to negative values and can no longer be used.

To assign arbitrary data to an item, use the [`.ItemData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa235132%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) property which is a Long and can hold integer values between [-2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263420%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your help but I've added values to my combo which their NewIndex were more than 32767. For example: Combo1.addItem ("Test") Combo1.ItemData(Combo1.NewIndex) = 1991000000 and code compiles correctly.

Comment: That example is setting the [`ItemData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa235132(v=vs.60).aspx) property which is different. It's a Long so can hold values from [-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263420(v=vs.60).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using the wrong numbers. An Integer is stored in a signed 32bits of memory (4 bytes), whose range is -2^31 to 2^31 = -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. A Long is stored in a signed 64 bits of memory (8 bytes), whose range is -2^63 to 2^63 = -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

**ItemData uses Integer data type**

Short is stored in a signed 16 bits (2 bytes), from -32,768 to 32,767. 
And a byte is a byte (unsigned 8 bites), from 0 to 255.

If you want to store binary figures (11001000000), convert them to integer. 
Jorge